# javascript java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code 400

Tags: javascript, java, ecmascript-6

I am invoking the Rest API using the below code to create User in target application, but if I am posting the duplicate user information in Postman, I am getting "400 Bad Request" with below data as JSON.

```
{
    "errorCode": "E0000001",
    "errorSummary": "Api validation failed: login",
    "errorLink": "E0000001",
    "errorId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "errorCauses": [
        {
            "errorSummary": "login: An object with this field already exists in the current organization"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the below code to get the response and unable to get the response when I am get "400 Bad Request".

Rest Call Details: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#create-user-with-password

In the API call, I am posting the Authorization token in the header `SSWS xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx`

I am posting the below data in the body.

```
{
    "profile": {
        "firstName": "John1",
        "lastName": "Flow1",
        "email": "john1.flow1@test.com",
        "login": "john1.flow1@test.com",
        "mobilePhone": ""
    },
    "credentials": {
        "password": {
            "value": "xxxxxxxx"
        }
    }
}
```

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: [https://test-app.testlab.com/api/v1/users"](https://test-app.testlab.com/api/v1/users%22)

```
function CreateUserInApp(rest_url, api_token, postJSON) {
    try {
        var postValBytes = new java.lang.String(postJSON).getBytes("UTF8");
        var posturl = new java.net.URL(rest_url);
        var stream = posturl.openConnection();
        stream.setRequestMethod("POST");
        stream.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        stream.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        stream.setRequestProperty("Authorization", api_token);
        stream.setDoOutput(true);
        stream.setDoInput(true);
        var outStream = stream.getOutputStream();
        outStream["write(byte[])"](postValBytes);
        outStream.flush();
        var responseCode = stream.getResponseCode();
        var stream = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(stream.getInputStream()));
        var inputLine;
        var response = new java.lang.StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = stream.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        var response = response.toString();
        return response;
    } catch(e) {
        return "ERROR Is: " + e.toString();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I am closing the connection properly or not, please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I mean... 400 means a bad request, we don't know the request you're making, what the request expects, or much else, so...

Comment: @DaveNewton could you please help me to debug this? This error is a generic error, how can I retrieve the full stack trace?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am trying to make a request of https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#create-user-with-password

Comment: A 400 means a bad request, so the thing I'd look at first is what is actually in the request, which we cannot see. You can also test your requests using Postman or similar tool.

Comment: @DaveNewton Using postman I can able to call this successfully, but using this code I am getting an error, I have pasted a link where you can find the API request details.

Comment: API docs show what's expected, not what you've sent.

Comment: @DaveNewton I added the JSON post data in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by using `getErrorStream()`, I updated the below code.

```
var stream_in = "";
if(responseCode == "200") {
    stream_in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(stream.getInputStream()));
} else {
    stream_in = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(stream.getErrorStream()));
}
```

Please suggest if I missed anything or anything I can improve on this.